# how to unit testing function that doesn't return value in phpunit?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

so this is the class that i want to test. and specifically i just pick one of the function that i want to test. while var is a value returned from doing some function from classB bar is instance from classC and then do some function which pass some variables. for most of the hints/example, the function to be tested is return a value. so my question is, how to test that this particular function worked?

thanks.

```
class mA extends A {
    ...
    function doSomething($foo) {
        $var = doStuffFromClassB("hallo");
        $bar = ClassC::instance();
        $bar->doStuffFromClassC($var, $foo, "world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's called `doSomething` and it doesn't indicate what it does by returning a value, then you can use [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) to trace the interaction with the other objects.

See PhpUnit's [documentation on mock objects](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html).  I guess in this case you want to verify that the `doStuffFromClassC` method is involved  with the var from `doStuffFromClassB`.

Comment: thanks 4 the suggestion. but i have following questions to ask:

[1] so to test those methods (doStuffFromClassB & C), should I write it in one test or write separate test for each doStuffFromClass*?

[2] or should I just need to test those methods from the TestCase of class B and C instead of test the void function in class mA?

Comment: For Unit testing, you want to isolate the class you are testing away from all of the implementation of other classes.  If mA's code just calls the methods on B and C, then verify that.  B and C can be unit tested separately.